# Blazor server app not working when deployed, works fine in Visual Studio

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server-side project which I've been developing in Visual Studio 2019, using .NET5. All has been working fine.

I've just deployed the site to a test server (which has two such sites already running on it, so I know the server has everything it needs to run the site), but none of the Blazor stuff seems to work. Specifically...

- Clicking on a button doesn't do anything
- Clicking on a link refreshes the entire page, instead of just rendering the new HTML
- Authorisation seems to be ignored, so a page with an `[Authorize]` attribute is visible to anyone

Don't know what code to show, as it all works when running in VS. Here is the contents of `App.razor`...

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
  <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
      <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
        <NotAuthorized>
          <RedirectToLogin />
        </NotAuthorized>
      </AuthorizeRouteView>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
      <AuthorizeView>
        <Authorized>
          <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <NotFound />
          </LayoutView>
        </Authorized>
        <NotAuthorized>
          <RedirectToLogin />
        </NotAuthorized>
      </AuthorizeView>
    </NotFound>
  </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

The `_Imports.razor` file contains all the right `using`s, specifically including...

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
```

Pages that are not supposed to be accessible to non-logged-in users are decorated with `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` in the code-behind or `@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` in the `.razor` file.

Anyone any ideas what I could have done wrong? Please advise if there is any more information I can give. Thanks

**Update** I just tried deploying the site to another domain on the same server, and it runs fine. I also tried pointing the other site to the folder for this one, and it worked fine (so it's not the deployed files), and then pointing this site to the other's folder, and it didn't work. So, it looks like there is something wrong with the site itself, but I ahve no idea what as it looks like the other.

Comment: Go check the Event Viewer on the Server if you're running on a Windows Server. Or similar for other operating systems.

This should give you a bigger picture of the issue. You should be getting errors.

Comment: @Marius No, nothing in the event viewer at all related to this site. Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: What's up, Avrohom ? Your code have some issues, probably not related to the main issue you're seemingly facing. I guess you first need to be sure that now your app is working fine, before you deal with petty things.

Comment: @enet Hello. Nope, the code itself it working fine. Please see the update to my question.

Comment: Thanks for following up, @AvrohomYisroel.  Please move your solution from the top of your question into a new answer below.  Self-answers are encouraged!  Also, feel free to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was nothing to do with my code, nor my site settings on the server. I use Cloudflare, and had set it to minify HTML. This removes the two HTML comments that are essential for Blazor to work. See [this article](https://zimmergren.net/solved-asp-net-core-blazor-web-sites-does-not-work-with-cloudflare-html-minification/) for more information.

So, if you are using Cloudflare, by all means set it to minify JavaScript and CSS, but DO not minify HTML.

Comment: You are a legend.

Comment: @KyleWhittington Hee hee, if only! All we have to do now is persuade Microsoft to find a better way of including the Blazor data in the page.

Comment: Ya saved the day

Comment: How did you even figure this out ??

Comment: See the article I linked in my answer. We found that after a lot of searching